# anticlockwise globe map, remove the shadow and increase the speed in css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Morning all,
I wanted to create an anticlockwise globe map. However, the map rotate clockwise for around 30 seconds and then it rotate anitclockwise. Also I want to remove the shadow as i am showing the globe in the my website which has a dark background color.

I want the globe to be rotate anticlockwise in the same speed as the rotating globe found in the fireeye. https://www.fireeye.com/cyber-map/threat-map.html

```css
.earth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/16.jpg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: -20px -20px 50px 2px #000 inset, 0 0 20px 2px #000;
  animation: spin 30s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth"></div>
```

My question is how to rotate the globe map in anticlockwise continuously.
Remove the shadow and increase the speed as the globe in the fireeye website.
Is it possible to show a brighter globe map?? Should I use another image to show a brighter map or is it possible to increase the brightness of the map

Comment: Can you put it into a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yke95m1k/1/

Comment: @kukkuz how did u do that??

Comment: you can click on the `snippet` button or do `ctrl+M`

Comment: @kukkuz, oooohh thank for the tip

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the shadow, remove this from the css rule:

```
    box-shadow:-20px -20px 50px 2px #000 inset, 0 0 20px 2px #000;
```

To speed it up, reduce the number of seconds on your animation.

To stop it switching directions, remove "alternate" from your animation

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yke95m1k/2/)

Comment: if i want anticlockwise by default how to do that??

Comment: but why is the earth stop rotating and start from all over again after some time

Comment: After rotating some time, the earth go back to the start posiition and rotate I want a smoooth flow in other words i do not want to earth to stop after some time

Comment: You need to add "infinite" to the animation also

Comment: I already add infinite, it happen the same thing to your code(jsfiddle). Observe the movement for around 5 seconds and then you will see that the globe stop all of a sudden

Comment: your background had to account for the roundness of the globe... try this

https://jsfiddle.net/yke95m1k/4/